# CMS - Advice on how to link to site?

Tags: hyperlinks, cms

We have a Content Management System (near enough).
The picture below is the Administration page, which is a flex based front end, viewed in a browser.

[image]

If you think of admin pages with most CMS, like Wordpress or Drupal, they have the ability to link to the main site.
Usually they do this with the name of the CMS instance (e.g. Dekho Blog) at the top of the page somewhere.

We need to have a link from this admin page to the main site.

**I would like to hear from the SE-UX community on your thoughts on the best way to go about this.**

One idea I had, was to make that Dekho image at the top, the link to the site.  Perhaps when you hove over it, it could glow or change colour?  However, I am no convinced this will be obvious.  At the same time, I quite like the simple nature of the admin page so do not want to over-complicate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention is that the site id or logo is placed at top left and links to the home page or main page of the site.

The reason this might not be obvious on your image is that the logo is not at top left, so if you were to move it, it would become more obvious via it's association with convention, as seen in the first image below.

It might also help the apparent lack of centralization as there are multiple features fighting for alignment here and the logo doesn't appear centralized.

However, I still feel there is a lack of distinctive border area around the logo which defines where the user is supposed to click, so alternatively, have a global navigation bar which separates itself from the main page content, as in the second image below. Then you also have a place to put other links if required (eg a '*Help*' link maybe useful for some - maybe not in your situation...)

[image]

[image]

Comment: will be going for your latter screenshot.  Thanks for the idea!